# can't install any apps

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I have **Ubuntu 16.04** on my computer. In the last few days, I **can't install** any new apps from however I try to install it (.deb files, Software Center, dash). I **can't even update** the apps I installed before encountering this problem.

Can anybody help me?

[image: how my software center appear when trying to look for updates]

Comment: Open a terminal by pressein Ctrl-Alt-T; run 'sudo apt update' and 'sudo apt upgrade' and update your question with the output of the two commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following commands:

```
rm ~/.local/share/gnome-software/*
sudo apt-get upgrade gnome-software
sudo apt-get update
```

This will solve the problem